# Sorting Least to Greatest

Tags: php

How do I sort a array from least to greatest?

So far I have only found greatest to least.

Here is my current code:

```
<?php
$person = Array ('100', '500', '200');
arsort($person, SORT_NUMERIC);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($person, true) . '</pre>';
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
asort($person, SORT_NUMERIC);

Array
(
    [0] => 100
    [2] => 200
    [1] => 500
)
```

To clarify : `arsort` actually stands for *array **reverse** sort*. So the opposit helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<?php

$person = array ('100', '500', '200');
sort($person);
print_r($person);

?>
```